# Azure App Service suddenly stopped with PhantomJS error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-linux

We have a Restify API running in Azure App Service on Linux for a while now. Suddenly this app (both test and prod, they run as seperate apps) stopped working. Based on the logs the error is related to a package we are using [node-highcharts-exporting](https://github.com/caihuiji/node-highcharts-exporting) which is dependent on PhantomJS. App Service is using Node 8.1.

We tried re-deploying the code, upgrading node version to 8.12 (do not want to use latest version with out testing) but still no luck.

Deployment Logs: (This part is successful. This is just for reference)

[image]

Container logs: (Startup fails here)

[image]

Tried to replicate the same environment on-prem and everything works fine. Created a new App Service which is also running into same issue. Any help is much appreciated.

**Update 1:** 
I think I figured out what is happening. This is related to font libraries on linux https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10904

I need to install `libfontconfig` but this is not supported on Azure App Service.

Comment: You could summarize it as a reply to close this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is due to sandbox restriction on a App Service. Just to highlight, the standard/native Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

Not supported scenarios on standard App Service - PhantomJS (/Selenium): tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.Known issue for all PDF generators based on wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs: custom fonts are not rendered (system-installed font is used instead) because of sandbox GDI API limitations.See App Service GitHub [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) page.

Based on your requirement, however you could use a **custom container in App Service** (You can use a custom Docker image) that lets you make OS changes that your app needs.

Checkout these document for more details on this topic:

Run a custom Linux container in Azure App Service (You can use a custom Docker image): https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker

Run a custom Windows container in Azure (Preview): 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

Comment: thank you.. that is what ended up doing but what I did not understand is, why it happened all of a sudden. This app is working fine for the last 8 moths or so. No change in the code or no new deployment.